Analytic continuation of the reciprocal of the zeta function.
I have been looking into the Riemann hypothesis, and it boils down to finding the zeros of the zeta function and proving all non trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ are in the form $\frac{1}{2}+it$. $\zeta(s)$ is a complex function, so zeros are difficult to find, but from what I understand complex integration can help. If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a curve C, then $\oint_C f(z)dz=0$ unless C contains a singularity of $f(z)$. To find the zeros of $f(z)$, we can integrate $\frac{1}{f(z)}$. With $\zeta(s)$ however,
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s},\Re(s)>1$$
which is an issue because all zeros of $\zeta(s)$ occur when $\Re(s)<1
$
As for the analytically continued formula for the zeta function,
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{}k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{1+n}(k+1)^s}}$$
which is an absolute mess.
My question is this: is there a way to either analytically continue $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ to the entire complex plane, or to evaluate $\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{}k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{1+n}(k+1)^s}}$ to something that doesn't involve reciprocals of nested infinite sums?

Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, I believe the Dirichlet series $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\right)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ actually converges for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$.

This question was also addressed on MathOverflow.

I don't think it is reasonable to expect that the Möbius function sum can be analytically continued to the left of the critical line because of the Riemann hypothesis, but I don't know for sure.
What can be done though is to accelerate the convergence of the reciprocal of the Möbius function sum:
$$\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}$$
to the right of the critical line.
The plot of the reciprocal of the Möbius function sum:
$$\Re\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{n=150}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{\frac{2}{3}+it}}\right)^{-1}\right) \label{1}\tag{1}$$
against the Riemann zeta function,
in Mathematica 14:
nn = 150;
sigma = 2/3;
Plot[Re[(1/Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n^(N[sigma] + I*t), {n, 1, nn}])], {t, 0, 
   60}, PlotStyle -> Gray];
Plot[Re[Zeta[N[sigma] + I*t]], {t, 0, 60}];
Show[%, %%]

looks like this:

where the gray curve is the truncated reciprocal Möbius function sum in \eqref{1}
and the blue curve which is hardly visible is the (analytically continued) usual Riemann zeta function:
$$\Re\left(\zeta(\frac{2}{3}+it)\right) \label{3}\tag{3}$$

As we see the convergence of the truncated Möbius function sum in \eqref{1} above is rather bad.

Now to accelerate the convergence of the Möbius function sum, I would do the following:
Create a triangular matrix
$$A(n,k) =[k|n]-[n=k](1+c)$$
where $[\;]$ is the Iverson bracket and the constant $c$ is chosen in the interval:
$$-1<c<0$$
Take the first column, call it $\mu_c(n)$, of the alternating matrix power sum of $A$, call it $B$:
$$B = \sum_{m=0}^{m=150}(-1)^{m}A^{m}$$
Then plot the reciprocal this new $\mu_c(n)$ sum:
$$\Re\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{n=150}\frac{\mu_{c}(n)}{n^{\frac{2}{3}+it}}\right)^{-1}+c\right) \label{2}\tag{2}$$
against the Riemann zeta function \eqref{3}, with the Mathematica 14 program:
nn = 150; (*increase nn for better precision*)
c = -3/4;  (*constant to vary in the range:-1<c<0*)
A = Table[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}] - 
   IdentityMatrix[nn]*(1 + c);
moebiusC = 
  N[ParallelSum[(-1)^(n + 0)*MatrixPower[A, n], {n, 0, nn}]][[All, 1]];
sigma = 2/3;
Plot[Re[(1/Sum[moebiusC[[n]]/n^(N[sigma] + I*t), {n, 1, nn}] + 
     c)], {t, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> Gray];
Plot[Re[Zeta[N[sigma] + I*t]], {t, 0, 60}];
Show[%, %%]


We then notice that the convergence looks better as long as we stay to the right of the critical line.

The annoying thing with this Möbius function acceleration is that the constant  $c$ ends up in the wrong place in \eqref{2}, and thereby does not even visually let us say anything about the location of the Riemann zeta zeros. Therefore I have not plotted the reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function, but the actual Riemann zeta function.


In other words: There seems to be a trade-off that the more precisely we can (at least visually) compute the Möbius function sum, the less it says about the location about the Riemann zeta zeros, and the closer we are to the actual Riemann zeta function the less the Möbius function sum converges, because of the constant $c$. Kind of like the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.


the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ is precisely the supremum of the real parts of the zeroes of $\zeta$ (it is obvious that the abscissa is at least that as convergent Dirichlet series are analytic; conversely one can show by Phragmen Lindelof say that if $\zeta$ has no zeroes in $\Re s > c$ so $\log \zeta$ is analytic and one can apply the three lines theorem there, that $1/|\zeta (\sigma+it)| <<_{\epsilon} |t|^{\epsilon}$ which implies by a standard moving integration to the left that the Dirichlet series of the Mobius function converges in $\Re s >c$

Thanks! Just two questions, 1. I am unfortunately not to familiar with matrices, and don't understand what [k|n]-n=k means, what are the dimensions, is it an upper or lower triangular matrix, etc. 2. Just wondering why you changed the power of n in the sum from s to 2/3+it? Thank you.
